# SQL Order By Wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

I have this MySQL Query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM school_staff WHERE DELETED = 'NO' AND BUILDING = '$building' ORDER by 
    Department != 'Principal',
    Department != 'Assistant Principal', 
    Department != 'Kindergarten', 
    Department != 'First Grade',
    Department != 'Second Grade',
    Department != 'Third Grade',
    Department != 'Fourth Grade',
    Department != 'Fifth Grade',
    Department != 'Learning Support',
    Department != 'Alternative Education', 
    Department != '% - Chair', 
    Department ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

How would I make the line: `Department != '% - Chair',` to make % any text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT in response to your comment:

I'd use a `CASE` statement. Something like

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Department LIKE '% - Chair' THEN 1 WHEN Department = 'Alternative Education' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

You can add as many WHEN statements into your CASE statement as you need.

Comment: Actually, What it is currently doing is displaying all the rows in $building, and if the Department column is sorted ascending with these terms. I am trying to get something like "Alternative Education - Chair" to appear before "Alternative Education". Essentially, trying to get Anything - Chair to appear before Anything. - http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?229494-MySQL-order-by-custom-list

Answer (score 0):

Did you try department Not Like '%Chair%

Answer (score 0):

use the SQL like operator in this scenario.

Try this:

```
Department NOT LIKE '% - Chair'
```